# Workaround or solution required: Unable to update plugins for NetBeans 12.0

Tags: netbeans, plugins

When I try to update plugins I receive message:

> The plugin JNA is requested in version >= 1.11 (release version 1) but only 2.3 (of release version different from 1) was found.

I am using latest plugins portal for Java/PHP and I have to use 8.2 portal for C/C++ support. Is there any solution or workaround to help me to update plugins?

[image: plugins update bocked]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4704
"I solved the problem by unchecking the NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal."

This worked for me too

Comment: I no longer get an error, but it is still not updating. It shows it downloading and installing the plugins, but then they are still on the list of updates after the IDE restarts.

Comment: it does the trick, unchecking NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal removed JNA plugin message and update runs smoothly